# val df_read_old = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","^").schema(old_schema).load("D:\\TESTSCALA\\"+"${lstfile}")

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val df_read_old = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","^").schema(old_schema).load("D:\\TESTSCALA\\"+"${lstfile}") // is not able to read file from variable.
```

Any other way to do this or i am missing some thing.

getting below error while file is available in given path:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/D:/TESTSCALA/${lstfile};
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
    at com.tmobile.dev.compare.serializedmaterial11$.main(test.scala:31)
    at com.tmobile.dev.compare.serializedmaterial11.main(test.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing **s string interpolator**

```
val df_read_old = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","^").schema(old_schema).load(s"D:\\TESTSCALA\\${lstfile}")
```

Comment: glad to hear please feel free to upvote and accept the answer @KumarUmang

Answer (score 1):

```
    val lstfile = ??? // your file here
  val old_schema = "" // your schema here
  val df_read_old = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","^").schema(old_schema)
    .load(s"D:\TESTSCALA\${lstfile}")
```

you have to use scala `s` string substitution properly like above example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should add s in front of "${lstfile}"

```
val df_read_old = spark.read.format(“csv”).option(“header”, “true”).option(“delimiter”,“^”).schema(old_schema).load(“D:\\TESTSCALA\\”+s“${lstfile}”)
```

//(or) alternatively add directly your variable to the path as its string

```
val df_read_old = spark.read.format(“csv”).option(“header”, “true”).option(“delimiter”,“^”).schema(old_schema).load(“D:\\TESTSCALA\\”+lstfile)
```